# Process started with PSEXEC. unable to read data from network drives

Tags: psexec

Process started as a administrator unable to read data from network drives. 
I solved this to add a policy **EnableLinkedConnections** in **regedit** and set value to 1. now it's working fine but when I started same process remotely with **psexec**. then process again unable to read data from network drives.
I am using this psexec command
**PsExec.exe \ipaddress -u username -p pasword -accepteula -i 1
"path"**

what should I do?